# How do I detect specific character names on fileupload in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging

Suppose I want to detect if a the file uploaded name contains `~`, `!` or `@`.  I know I'm dead wrong with my attempts below so ow would I go about doing it the correct way (for the sake of good practice)?  I've tried:

```
str_contains($asset->getClientOriginalName(), "~", "!", "@");
```

and

```
preg_match('/[^~!@\d]/', $asset->getClientOriginalName());
```

Comment: Before you ask this kind of a question, you should ask yourself which part went wrong. In your case: are you obtaining the name of the file wrong, or are you checking for the character wrong? if you get the correct filename (easy check, print the file name) then this question has nothing to do with file upload and vise versa

Comment: @HTMHell I'm grabbing the file name correctly and have verified that via `dd($asset->getClientOriginalName());`.  Since that's out of the way, now I need to know how to check for specific characters.

Comment: great, so now we don't have to know it's a name of a file you uploaded, you can refer to it as a string. just a little tip for your next questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`str_contains()` can only compare one thing at a time, so you'd need to use three of them:

```
if (
    str_contains($asset->getClientOriginalName(), '~') ||
    str_contains($asset->getClientOriginalName(), '!') ||
    str_contains($asset->getClientOriginalName(), '@')
) {
    // filename contains the string
}
```

Or, to do the equivalent via `preg_match()`, you'd have to use an inclusive group:

```
if (preg_match('/[~!@]/', $asset->getClientOriginalName()) {
    // filename contains the string
}
```